# BOT framework integration - 502 Bad Gateway - Failed to send activity:

Tags: botframework

BOT framework integration - 502 Bad Gateway - Failed to send activity:  There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError

Description of the issue:

We are developing BOT with Microsoft BOT framework. The BOT resides on company premises and will communicate with dev.botframework.com utilizing web chat channel . For the authentication part of the internet enabled site(residing on companyinfra) to be integrated with dev.botframework.com for one BOT app we have following configurations

The BOT end points which we have created are using the wild card certificate with x509.v3 compliance, but as its wild card certificate , it is being used by many internet sites in enterprise
and SSL wildcard certificate doesn’t have the exact host name

SSL wild card Certificate Name : *..com
Our host names are:

https://env name.domain name.com

SSL wild card certificate which we are using is part of the CRL
But as per the guidelines from Microsoft published in below 2 URLs, it seems that certificate should not be part of CRL and also should have exactly same host name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication
Microsoft/BotBuilder#3418

The above guidelines state that:
Most of the checks for "current and valid" are standard checks for server SSL certificates: the Certificate Name must match the hostname, it must not be expired, it must not be listed in a CRL, it must have the correct set of EKUs,

So we have 2 mismatching points in our implementation around the certificates.
Please let us know with these 2 points , if the integration of our premises BOT with dev.botfrmework.com will work seamlessly ?